# (QEMU) -audio coreaudio,model=sb16 doesn't create sound card for guest

Tags: linux, audio, virtual-machine, sound-card, qemu

I'm trying to create an Alpine virtual machine on MacOS (macos host) and I want to be able to play sound from my QEMU VM. I have tried the config listed in the title as well as "-audiodev driver=coreaudio,id=coreaudio -device sb16,audiodev=coreaudio" but whenever I go into the VM, I try "arecord -l" and get "arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...". "/sbin/lsmod | grep snd" returns nothing.

I'd expect it to at least create the sound card but apparently not. I haven't been able to find help for this anywhere. Completely lost.

Comment: Ok so partial solution: I changed from using sb16 to hda since it seems more common but now My problem is that the sound card is listed under lspci but aplay -l still doesn't recognize it and gives the error above.